# Where do penalties for being offline go? (for validators)

Tags: proof-of-stake

Where do penalties for being offline go? (for validators)
In POS when validator is being offline he loses part of its stake (depends on correlation with other validators being offline aka partial slashing)

So is that `slashed stake` will be burned or what?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were Ethereum 2.0 Specifications posted a couple of hours ago.

If we take a look at [penalize_validator function](https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/v0.1/specs/core/0_beacon-chain.md#penalize_validator) we can observe that slashed money will got to whistleblower.

Comment: Since you answered your own question, remember to check it as the accepted answer.